# Django - Send bulk email using send_mass_mail()

Tags: django, email

I tried to send mass email using loop and it worked. However, the entire process takes long duration to complete with increase in the number of recipients. So I decided to send email using send_mass_email(). Unfortunately my code dont seem to work. Nor am I able to find the problem. Please help.

**view:**

```
def noticeboard(request):
    title = "Notice Board"
    emaillists = []
    given_value = request.POST.get('radioGroup')
    if given_value == 'All':
        emaillist = MyUser.objects.all().values_list('email', flat=True)
        for email in emaillist:
            emaillists.append(str(email.encode('utf8')))
    if given_value == 'XYZ':
    .....
    .....

    form = noticeboardForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():                
        FROM = "noticeboard@gmail.com"    
        SUBJECT = form.cleaned_data.get('subject').decode('utf-8')
        TEXT = form.cleaned_data.get('body').decode('utf-8')
        message = (SUBJECT, TEXT, FROM, emaillist)
        try:
            connection = get_connection()  
            connection.open()      
            send_mass_mail(message, fail_silently=False)
            connection.close() 
            print('successfully sent the mail')
        except:
            print("failed to send mail")            

        return redirect('delivery_success')

    return render(request, "noticeboardform.html", {"form": form, "title": title})


def delivery_success(request):
    return render(request, 'delivery_success.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django docs says the first parameter should be a data tuple.

```
send_mass_mail((message,), fail_silently=False)
```

See if this works.

Comment: Please check if that is true. Write a `print` statement and see if it prints anything. You'll know if code is getting into `is_valid()` block.

Comment: It works. My mistake. The body of my email was not getting collected. Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks @MiniGunnR. :)

Comment: Print `message` variable and see if the format is the same as `('Subject here', 'Here is the message', 'from@example.com', ['first@example.com', 'other@example.com'])`. That is what is given in Django docs.

Comment: Also, there are two variables, `emaillist` and `emaillists`, see if you are using the right one.